# Android : How do I set the DatePicker value in an EditText which I created multiple in a loop

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-datepicker

I have created multiple number of EditText dynamically by using loop. So I have created multiple EditText with the same name. I'am calling the DatePickerDialog when i click an EditText. I can choose the date and am setting done. Once it is completed the chosen date is only setting to the last EditText which I have created.

I want to set the date for all the EditText. Is it possible to set the value in an EditText which is created with the same name?

This is my code.

```
for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
estimate_closedate = new EditText(getActivity());
        estimate_closedate.setLayoutParams(params1);
        estimate_closedate.setWidth(1000);
        estimate_closedate.setHint("Estimated Close Date");
estimate_closedate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                        mDateSetListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        myear = year;
        mmonth = monthOfYear + 1;
        mday = dayOfMonth;
        if (mmonth < 10) {
            month = 0 + Integer.toString(mmonth);
        } else {
            month = Integer.toString(mmonth);
        }
        if (mday < 10) {
            day = 0 + Integer.toString(mday);
        } else {
            day = Integer.toString(mday);
        }
        nextdate = (new StringBuilder().append(myear).append("-")
                .append(month).append("-").append(day)).toString();
        estimate_closedate.setText(nextdate);           
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (see my `comments`) :

```
for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
        EditText estimate_closedate = new EditText(getActivity()); //create new instance
        estimate_closedate.setId(i); //set the id (0-4)
        estimate_closedate.setLayoutParams(params1);
        estimate_closedate.setWidth(1000);
        estimate_closedate.setHint("Estimated Close Date");
        estimate_closedate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context,
                        mDateSetListener, myear, mmonth, mday);
                dpd.show();
            }
        });
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        myear = year;
        mmonth = monthOfYear + 1;
        mday = dayOfMonth;
        if (mmonth < 10) {
            month = 0 + Integer.toString(mmonth);
        } else {
            month = Integer.toString(mmonth);
        }
        if (mday < 10) {
            day = 0 + Integer.toString(mday);
        } else {
            day = Integer.toString(mday);
        }
        nextdate = (new StringBuilder().append(myear).append("-")
                .append(month).append("-").append(day)).toString();
        //estimate_closedate.setText(nextdate);
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
           EditText estimate_closedate = (EditText) findViewbyId(i); //get the id previously set
           estimate_closedate.setText(nextdate);
        }           
        }
    }
};
```

The point is in `setId` when you create the `EditText` and `findViewbyId` to find the created `EditText`, using `for` loop.

Comment: Here the problem is if i set the value for one EditText then it applies to all the EditText.

Comment: @user3764346 You can use if-else in the `for` loop i created. No offense, but im here to help you, not to code for you